# Resistor test mode in ICT

Tags: resistors

My ICT machine has 2 resistance measurement modes on the PCB:

Mode 1: Constant current mode for each resistance value (Figure 1). In this mode, we apply the formula V = I * R to calculate R.

Mode 2: Connect the resistor to be measured in parallel with a capacitor (Figure 2). Constant voltage VDC = 0.2V, let C saturate, Ic=0, and we calculate R using the formula V = I × R.

In practical testing of PCBs using the ICT machine, why do people often recommend using mode 2 instead of mode 1?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have a (large, say 1000 uF) capacitor in parallel to a 100 kΩ resistor, it will take a long time until you have saturated your capacitor with a weak current source (2.5 uA) and only see the current flowing though the resistor. Method 2 is most probably faster. ICT is normally used for mass production so production speed is key.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think it's one of the reasons. My mentor suggests an alternative question that why Mode 1 is not recommended? It could be related to the safety.

Comment: @HoàiNamNguyễn I’ve never seen an ICT system with enough compliance voltage to hurt anyone.

Comment: Yes but it might damage the circuit, right? Can you explain more about the voltage change mechanism in Mode 1, and whether it could potentially damage the circuit board?

Comment: @HoàiNamNguyễn You program your ICT test accordingly. If one node would be destroyed by 2.5 uA, don’t apply it.

Comment: Yes, so maybe a fixed voltage would be a better option. Thank you for your advice!