# Capacitor test mode in ICT

Tags: capacitor, measurement

My ICT machine has two capacitor measurement modes on the PCB:

Mode 1: Use DC source test method (Figure 1)

[image]

Mode 2: Use AC source test method (Figure 2)

[image]

Could anyone please help me with the questions: What is the importance of each mode? When do we use mode 1? When do we use mode 2? It is best if we could compare these two modes.

Comment: You copied some 3rd party material into your question. Please cite its source.

Comment: Near identical: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/697906/resistor-test-mode-in-ict

Comment: The other one is a different circuit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the material you quote, DC source is used for measuring 'large' capacitors.
AC impedance is therefore used for measuring 'small' capacitors.

Check the ICT machine specifications to see whether the ranges overlap in 'medium sized' capacitors, where you could use either method.

Comment: Could you please explain why DC source is useful for large capacitors? Similarly, why AC is suitable for small ones? Thank you!

Comment: @HoàiNamNguyễn   With 'small' capacitors, the charge time is too small to measure accurately with a practical charging current. With large capacitors, the impedance is too small to measure accurately at a practical frequency. For definitions of 'large', 'small', and 'practical', read the specifications of your ICT machine.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance, it is the correct answer